# Beamer & tikz: size picture = max all slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

Usually I like to draw a picture, and then on the next slide, add something to it. The problem is that the size of the picture is then changed, so the picture moves in the `beamer` presentation, which is really not very beautiful.

How could I easily say to `beamer` to take the max size of the image after all the addition?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle,fill=black] (a) {};
    \node<2->[draw,fill=black,above=of a] (b) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and a picture of what I have:

[image]

and here is what I want:

[image]

Do you know how to do that automatically? (I always use positioning, so manually estimate the bounding box, and then use `useasboundingbox` is quite dirty).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\visible` will reserve necessary the room:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle,fill=black] (a) {};
    \visible<2->{\node[draw,fill=black,above=of a] (b) {};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]